# 2 lambdas and one VPC - only one can access the internet/DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm running into a very weird problem with AWS lambdas. I've created two lambdas, A and B. Both are configured the exact same way. Both need to access the Internet and DynamoDB. I'm trying to move them into a new VPC. The lambdas are in subnets because I'm using DAX.

The old VPC has 2 private subnets split /24. The new one has 3 private subnets split /20. Both VPCs have a public subnet split /24 and /20 respectively. There is a NAT attached to the subnets in the route table for the private subnets, and an IGW attached to the public subnets.

Security groups for both have (Inbound) all traffic with the source security group, and a custom TCP Rule for 8111, and (Outbound) 0.0.0.0/0.

Moving lambda A to the new VPC works fine. It can access both the Internet and DynamoDB. That tells me that the NAT and IGW are configured correctly (I think).

Moving lambda B to the new VPC fails. It can't access either the Internet or DynamoDB.

Moving either lambda back to the old VPC works. The cluster endpoint for DAX isn't hardcoded in either lambda, so there isn't an issue where I'm not changing the code correctly.

Moving a lambda entails changing the VPC, the subnets, and security groups to match the correct VPC. And changing the DAX cluster endpoint.

Both the old and new VPCs have endpoints set up for DynamoDB for both the public and private subnets.

Any thoughts on what I should be looking at?

Comment: Just try checking this: use lambda A SecGrp into lambda B.. and check?

Comment: I can't. Security groups are tied to a VPC. So I can't swap them between VPCs.

In each VPC, my security groups are shared. They are using the same security group.

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: ok, i dont see any reason for not working.. Could you try delete and recreate NAT? 
also verify you have also allowed lambda's traffic in DAX cluster SG

Comment: Just checking: did you temporarily increase the execution timeout to a large enough value to let the function *really* fail properly to the point that it throws an exception?  You may learn more that way than if the execution is killed by Lambda due to typically short timeouts.

Comment: It's currently running at 2.5 minutes for the execution timeout. The function is when it gets a trigger from DynamoDB, it goes out to the web to scrape a page. It's not getting anywhere near there and is completing in a few microseconds, since it can't get to the web or DAX/DynamoDB. The stream is calling the lambda, and the lambda completes correctly - without doing anything.

Comment: What are the actual errors that the second lambda is outputting?

Comment: Error: client: no endpoints available, and a null error from the web call meaning it can't reach the internet.